# How can I set focus on a form input inside jScrollPane?

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-jscrollpane

An outsourcer implemented jScrollPane on our project some time ago and I discovered its preventing me from setting focus on form text inputs inside it. If I remove jScrollPane I can easily set focus with:

```
$("#myField").focus();
```

I've been through jScrollPane for some time this afternoon but I can't find the cause of the problem.

Comment: where are you calling `$("#myField").focus()` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @anurupr, you solved it for me. You made me realize jScrollPane was not being called from the Javascript file. I found the call in the main php file and was then able to set the focus after jScrollPane which fixed it.

I've answered my own question in order to mark this thread as answered.